# What is the meaning of the seed in the tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm a beginner at TensorFlow, and my book said I should put this code first to produce the same sequence of results.

```
seed = 3
np.random.seed(seed)
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
```

I put various values in seed, and the results showed a big difference.

Does it affect the initial value setting of weights?
What exactly does that seed value setting play?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed

Answer (score 1):

This is not a term which is specific for TensorFlow. Almost every programming language have a seed for to determine *randomness* of the random number generators etc. With seeds you can re-produce your results. For to reproduce results you need to restart kernel see the difference. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
seed = 3
np.random.seed(seed)
tf.random.set_seed(seed)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, activation="relu", input_shape = (28,28,1), kernel_initializer=initializer))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer=initializer))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This will give, 1st run:

```
>> model.get_weights()
[array([[-1.036157  ,  0.19191754]], dtype=float32),
 array([0., 0.], dtype=float32),
 array([[-0.86388123],
        [-0.8873284 ]], dtype=float32),
 array([0.], dtype=float32)]
```

If you create the same model for the second time:

```
>> model.get_weights()

[array([[-0.4151404 ,  0.81533253]], dtype=float32),
 array([0., 0.], dtype=float32),
 array([[ 0.39391458],
        [-0.48291653]], dtype=float32),
 array([0.], dtype=float32)]
```

> produce the **same sequence** of results

Now, **restart the kernel** and create the model again. Results should be same for first and second run.

If you want to create a model with exact same weights everytime, you need to do:

```
initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(seed=seed)

model.add(Dense(2, activation="relu", input_shape = (28,28,1), kernel_initializer=initializer))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer=initializer))

>> model.get_weights()

[array([[-0.6233864,  1.5557635]], dtype=float32),
 array([0., 0.], dtype=float32),
 array([[-0.6233864],
        [ 1.5557635]], dtype=float32),
 array([0.], dtype=float32)]
```

will be same, does not matter how many times you create the model, even after restarting kernel.